# Dataframe - round up to N decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

i have a pandas dataframe which has floating values:

| columnA |
| --- |
| 1.234567 |
| 8.901234 |

i want to round each of these values **up** to 2 decimal places.

i.e.

| columnA |
| --- |
| 1.24 |
| 8.91 |

i've checked a [handful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481649/rounding-off-columns-to-two-decimal-place) of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272024/round-each-number-in-a-python-pandas-data-frame-by-2-decimals) but using 'round' won't round up and using 'ceil' rounds to whole numbers.

any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can scale up and then divide down: `df['columnA'] = np.ceil(df['columnA'] * 100) / 100`

Comment: Or with `df['columnA'] = df['columnA'].apply(my_ceil, precision=2)` from the linked duplicate.

Comment: Do you need to worry about negative numbers?

Comment: no, shouldn't have any negatives

Comment: yep, those are what i was looking for. thanks @HenryEcker and stack bot!